# removing "class" and "data-toggle" from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to disable clicking on a bootstrap dropdown because I've hover implemented. I have done this by removing `class` and `data-toggle` from the `<a>` tag.

Original declaration:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

disable clicking:

```
<a href="#" Programs <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

But for smaller screens, i.e. mobile, I want to enable clicking on a dropdown since hover would not be possible. How would I do this?

Comment: Adding or removing classes or any custom attributes **does not disable clicking**. If you want to disable clicking use `onclick="return false;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not both?

```
<a href="#" class="hidden-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs <b class="caret"></b></a>
<a href="#" class="visible-xs"> Programs <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

This way only 1 of the 2 dropdown will be visible to end user at any given view port. Note the first one uses `hidden-xs` class while the other uses `visible-xs`.

Comment: What I was trying to do was the opposite of what you have given. Nevertheless, thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Use .visible-xs and .visible-sm to make things visible only on small screens (mobile & tablet).

You can use .hidden-md and .hidden-lg to hide things on desktop.